# Text file parsing using HashMap and List

Tags: java, list, parsing, hashmap

I have a textfile like:

```
fruits bananna blackbery apple
vegetable carrot potato
cars toyota honda ww bmw
```

I need my Java program to take a string like `vegetable` and display the next words in line. In this case the program will display `carrot potato`

I have the code below:

```
public static void ParseWithHashMap(String wordGiven) throws IOException {

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> lemmes = new ArrayList<String>();

        FileInputStream fin = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
            isr = new InputStreamReader(fin, "UTF-8");
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                String[] toks = line.split("\\s+");

                for (int i = 1; i < toks.length; i++) {
                    lemmes.add(toks[i]);

                }
                map.put(toks[0], lemmes);
                line = br.readLine();

            }
        } finally {

        }

        System.out.println(map.get(wordGiven));
    }
```

The problem is, when I type `fruits` the program will display all the words from textfile except first word of each line

```
bananna blackbery apple carrot potato toyota honda ww bmw
```

, and I want to show me the words that follow the word that I give, in this case would be

```
bananna blackbery apple
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there duplicate keys in your file? I mean multiple "fruits" tags or any other tag?

Comment: Duplicate keys no, but duplicate values of the keys yes (banana, potato, banana)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare/define your `ArrayList` within the while loop `while (line != null) {`.

Reason being once you start adding the data to this list, it would accumulate till the end of your file which you do not want. Instead you just want it to hold the values for the current line only.

Hence,

```
  while (line != null) {
       ArrayList<String> lemmes = new ArrayList<String>();
       ...
```

Should get you the desired results.

Comment: That is correct. Thank you! If I would have 15 reputation I would give you +1

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `List#clear` after you have added the `arraylist` to your `map` without changing your code.

```
map.put(toks[0], lemmes);
lemmes.clear();
```